# Labelling Form Controls HTML with `input` tag

Tags: html, input, label

I am reading ***HTML and CSS*** by Jon Duckett, and I am reading about labelling form controls using the `label` tag.

The example that he has shown is given below.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Labelling Form Controls</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="http://www.example.org/subscribe.php">
  <label>Age: <input type="text" name="age" /></label>
  <br />
  Gender:
  <input id="female" type="radio" name="gender" value="f">
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input id="male" type="radio" name="gender" value="m">
  <label for="male">Male</label>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, in the example he provided, he has not closed the input tags for the `female` and `male` radio options.

My question is, as the radio buttons are self-closing, should they be closed as shown below, or not?

```
<input id="female" type="radio" name="gender" value="f" />
<label for="female">Female</label>
<input id="male" type="radio" name="gender" value="m" />
<label for="male">Male</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to make `<input>` tags self-closing in HTML5, they're considered empty elements which can't have children. Therefore self-closing them would be redundant.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/empty_element